# Authenticating to YouTube with AuthSub

Tags: php, youtube, zend-framework, authsub

I am finding two conflicting accounts from Google. I think because the developer guide hasn't been updated. I have received my httpClient (I think) and I am now to this point in the developer guide:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);
```

When I go to check my developer key and try to seach for an application id and client id I find this paragraph:

> The Developer Key should be provided in every YouTube API request. Learn more
>   Note that you no longer need to provide a Client ID with YouTube API requests.
>   You may request an Apiary client key here.

So what should I use for the application and client IDs? I have tried leaving them blank and using arbitrary stings. Here is the error I get when I try to post a comment:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 401 
<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
<TITLE>User authentication required.</TITLE> 
</HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> 
<H1>User authentication required.</H1> 
<H2>Error 401</H2> 
</BODY> 
</HTML> 
in /home/justinrob/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php:709 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/justinrob/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata.php(221): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array, '<atom:entry xml...', 'application/ato...', NULL) 
#1 /home/justinrob/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(900): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array, '<atom:entry xml...', 'application/ato...') 
#2 /home/justinrob/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(975): Zend_Gdata_App->post(Object(Zend_Gdata_YouTube_CommentEntry), 'http://gdata.yo...', NULL, NULL, Array) 
#3 /home/justinrob/mhjrmusic.com/common/zend/tests/bootstrap.php(99): Zend_Gdata_App->insertEntry(Object(Zend_Gdata_YouTube_CommentEn in /home/justinrob/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 709
```